# Configure code-coverage to ignore or accept private constructors

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-coverage

Is there a way in intellij-idea (version 11.1.5) to ignore or accept certain parts of code?

In my configuration I am using IDEA as the coverage runner.

I currently have a static class with a private constructor.

This constructor is never supposed to be call.

Is there anything I can do such that code-coverage understands this?

I just want to make it easier for myself to know that indeed I have complete coverage rather than looking at each class and making sure that I didn't miss anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Received a response from JetBrains.  It seems that this is not possible as of this posting, but there is an open ticket.

http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5510539#5510539

Answer (score 0):

You may have to search for static code analysis (assistance).
[Intelligent Code Assistance](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/code_analysis.html)

Answer (score 0):

I failed to find already existing solution with IntelliJ.

I created annotations by myself.

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR})
public @interface ExcludeFromCoverage_PrivateConstructor_Obviously {

}
```

And added the `@ExcludeFromCoverage_PrivateConstructor_Obviously` to

- Settings

  - Coverage

    - Java Coverage

      - Exclude annotations

Now my private constructors are free from the coverage.

```java
    @ExcludeFromCoverage_PrivateConstructor_Obviously
    private Some() {
        throw new AssertionError("instantiation is not allowed");
    }
```